# ASP.NET Core 2.0 IAuthorizationService And Expired Bearer Tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization

I'm been working on an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application using Bearer tokens.  Everything in relation to the tokens and authentication is/has been working fine.

I have just implemented a different authorization process.  Now rather than using the `Authorize` attribute to enforce policies I'm making use of the `IAuthorizationService` and `DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider` approach.

However, I'm seeing something I didn't expect to see and cannot figure out a solution or find any useful documentation on the problem.

I am configuring the bearer tokens in `Startup.cs` like this:

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
  options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
});
```

The validation parameters are built like this:

```
return new TokenValidationParameters
{
  // The signing key must match!
  ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
  IssuerSigningKey = GetSymmetricSecurityKey(configuration),
  ValidateIssuer = true,
  ValidIssuer = configuration.GetSection("TokenAuthentication:Issuer").Value,
  ValidateAudience = true,
  ValidAudience = configuration.GetSection("TokenAuthentication:Audience").Value,
  ValidateLifetime = true,
  ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // leave at zero, we validate expiry!
};
```

My Authorisation setup code looks like this:

```
public static void AddAuthorisationPolicies(this IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddAuthorization();
  services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
  services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, AuthorisationPolicyProvider>();
  services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, RoleClaimHandler>();
}
```

This is all working as expected.  In my controllers I can now inject an instance of the authorisation service like this:

```
public SyncController(IAuthorizationService auth)
```

My requirements and handlers are all working as expected and so forth.  Now in action method controllers I can do this:

```
var auth = await authz.AuthorizeAsync(User, "Administrator");
if (!auth.Succeeded)
{
  return Challenge();
}
...
```

When the token is valid the `ClaimsPrinciple` is correctly set meaning the call to `AuthorizeAsync` is performed with a valid user.

What I'm seeing that I didn't expect to see is that with an expired `Bearer` token the request is still reaching the action methods, but with a null `ClaimsPrinciple`.

I must be missing some key setup somewhere.  I didn't expect to see this happening and it doesn't make any sense to invoke `AuthorizeAsync` with a null user.  Strictly speaking this hasn't opened any security hole since with a null user a call to `AuthorizeAsync` will always fail, but it's not particularly clean, sensible or logical.

**How can I prevent a request with an expired token from getting this far through the request pipeline?**

Is this in fact expected behaviour or do I have to roll my own process (more Middleware?) for this expiration check now that I'm bypassing the built in `AuthorizeAttribute` logic?

I expected the `ValidateLifetime = true` to continue to reject the request as I have changed how the Authorisation works, not the Authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have an authorize attribute on your controller (or applied globally) authentication isn't going to run until you call the authorization service, because it doesn't know that your controller needs an authenticated user.

Adding a simple [Authorize] to the controller would validate the bearer token before it gets into the action methods.

Comment: <slaps forehead> of course!!  Seems so obvious now you've pointed that out.  Thanks!